# How to go back after playing video

Tags: android, video, playback

I have an application that makes a list of videos with play button. When I click on the play button, a separate activity is started using intent. I just want that when the video playback is finished, the activity should automatically finish itself and go back to the main Activity. Here is my code for creating videoview.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    setContentView(R.layout.videoview);
    Intent i = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
    filename = extras.getString("videofilename");
    mVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoview);
    path=filename;
    if (path == "") {

        Toast.makeText(
                ViewVideo.this,
                "no video selected,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } else {

          mVideoView.setVideoPath(path);
          mc = new MediaController(this);
          mVideoView.setMediaController(mc);
          mVideoView.requestFocus();
              mVideoView.start();

    }
}
```

any suggestions???

Answer (score 4):

Register an [OnCompletionListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html#setOnCompletionListener%28android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener%29) to the videoView, in the listener implement the call to `finish()`.

Edit (to answer to comment):

use the method [setOnCompletionListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html#setOnCompletionListener%28android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener%29):

```
mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion (MediaPlayer mp) {
        // your code to clean up and finish the activity...
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more; I am kind of new to android. I shall be thankful to you if you tell me how to register onCompletionListener to the videoview.. Thanks

Comment: I tried it Sir and used Log.v() and finish() as well to see if this function is called but it isn't being called.. Can you tell me sir where to put this code in my code.. i may be putting it at the wrong place..

Comment: put it before `mVideoView.start()`.

Comment: What was the error - `@Override` is an annotation tells Java that you are intending to override a method of the super class.

Comment: @Farhan let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1416/discussion-between-mbyd-and-farhan)

Answer (score 3):

You can set a `MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener` on the `VideoView` using `VideoView.setOnCompletionListener`, you'll then be able to finish the containing activity when the video finishes playing.