# using if statement when video is done playing

Tags: android, video

i want to use an if statement after the video is done playing
if b1 is pressed video1 is playing and after that it returns to home screen of the app

I have 4 videos

can someone help me?

if video is done playing return to home

Comment: Home screen of your app or home screen of the Android device ?

Comment: home screen of the app because in the current setup it goes directly to the home screen of the device

Comment: Please refer to this link, this might be the one you are looking for :   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681539/how-to-go-back-after-playing-video

Answer (score 3):

you can set OnCompletionListener by calling setOnCompletionListener  method of MediaPlayer.
OnCompletionListener interface have method onComplete which will be called when mediaPlayer finishes playing and then you can call your app home activity e.g.

```
mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new
    OnCompletionListener() {        
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
        Intent stopplay= new Intent(MyRecording.this,Recorded_Message.class);
        startActivity(stopplay);                
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Do like this.

```
videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
          Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);
     i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

use this flag to remove your activity stack

```
 Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
```